# Gdk-Message: 18:24:29.350: Error reading events from display: Connection reset by peer

Tags: google-chrome-os, crostini

so i was installing the itch.io app, and since i'm on chrome os, I downloaded the linux version. It didn't come with an extension, so I had no idea how to run it. No biggie, I ran it using the command line.
Returned:
Gdk-Message: 18:24:29.350: Error reading events from display: Connection reset by peer

i tried: wtf was i supposed to try?
i expected: no error and itch.io installing properly
what happened: returned `Gdk-Message: 18:24:29.350: Error reading events from display: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: Did you install it on Debian linux on chromeos?